# How to hide shell process information when starting background process?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

```
[USER@SERVER ~] sleep 3 &
[1] 5232
[USER@SERVER ~] 
[1]+  Done                    sleep 3
[USER@SERVER ~]
```

How do I /dev/null these two messages?:

```
[1] 5232
[1]+  Done                    sleep 3
```

p.s.: so I need the output of the process, but not the mentioned two lines!

Comment: You only get those lines when you run it interactively. You don't if you run it from a script, for example.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's not the program output, it's some useful shell information.

Anyway, those can be hided by using subshell and output redirection

```
( sleep 3 & ) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: "2>/dev/null" is the good thing, i need the output from the process

Comment: @LanceBaynes The process could also write something on stderr.

Comment: It's unfortunate that this defeats the retrieval of pid with $!

Comment: This not write on $! variable

Answer (score 6):

In bash or zsh, you can call `disown %1` to tell the shell to forget about the job. Then the shell won't print any message about that job, nor will it show it when you run `jobs` or ever send a SIGHUP to it. In zsh, starting the job with `&!` instead of `&` is equivalent to calling `disown` on it immediately.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
user@host:~$ read < <( sleep 10 & echo $! )
user@host:~$ echo $REPLY
28677
```

And you have hidden both the **output** and the **PID**. Note that you can still retrieve the **PID** from $REPLY

Comment: This is brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment (yet) on @Gilles but it seems that `& disown` also works in bash:

```
sleep 3 & disown
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Bash v.4.1.2